# Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 when using Unirest API

Tags: php

I am using php5.6 and wamp5 1.6.5.

I am trying simply code as below

```
$response=Unirest\Request::get("https://indianpost.p.mashape.com/getPincodes.php?name=delhi",array("X-Mashape-Key" => "mykey","Accept" => "application/json"));
```

Then i am getting below errors.Can any help me out from here.

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
C:\wamp\www\myapplication\index.php on line 11

Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING in 
C:\wamp\www\myapplication\index.php on line 11
```

Please help me.

This is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
     // These code snippets use an open-source library.
       $response = 
     Unirest\Request::get("https://indianpost.p.mashape.com/getPincodes.php?
     name=delhi",array("X-Mashape-Key" => "mykey","Accept" => 
     "application/json"));
    ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is line 11?  Add the lines before it in the file.

Comment: Yes that line number is 11.

Comment: As i am thinking Unirest\Request in that backward slash is cause of problem.

Comment: Can you show lines between 1 and 11?

Comment: please see above code as i updated.